# Proper way of using derived map type index in golang

Tags: go

It could be a beginner's question. Code is like,

```
type MYMAP map[int]int

func (o *MYMAP) dosth(){
    //this will fail to compile
    o[1]=2
}
```

error message: invalid operation: o[1] (index of type *MYMAP)

How to access the underlying type of MYMAP as map?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem isn't that it's an alias, it's that it's a pointer to a map.

Go will not automatically deference pointers for map or slice access the way it will for method calls. Replacing `o[1]=2` with `(*o)[1]=2` will work. Though you should consider why you're (effectively) using a pointer to a map. There can be good reasons to do this, but usually you don't need a pointer to a map since maps are "reference types", meaning that you don't need a pointer to them to see the side effects of mutating them across the program.

Answer (score 5):

An easy fix could be done by getting rid of pointer, just change `o *MYMAP` to `o MYMAP`

```
type MYMAP map[int]int

func (o MYMAP) dosth(){
    o[1]=2
}
```

Comment: Note that calling `make` inside a receiver function won't do what you might expect - once you leave the receiver function, your map will be left unchanged.
If you want to call `make` inside the receiver function, you'll need to use pointers.